# Skip prompt with reg delete

Tags: windows

i am running a reg delete command with"/f" at the end, but still i get the prompt for input yes/no answer. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Example:

```
REG DELETE "HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper" /v  /f
```